# TurtleBot gmapping and amcl demos FATAL footprint error for move_base

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

([Ticket 5185](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5185) submitted.)

Using the latest Electric debians for the TurtleBot stack, running either the gmapping or amcl demo throws a FATAL move_base error as follows:

```
[ INFO] [1317172658.105549257]: Received a 320 X 512 map at 0.050000 m/pix

[FATAL] [1317172658.745797230]: The footprint must be specified as list of lists on the parameter server, /move_base/global_costmap/footprint was specified as [] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'

    what(): The footprint must be specified as list of lists on the parameter server with at least 3 points eg: [[x1, y1], [x2, y2], ..., [xn, yn]]

[move_base-9] process has died [pid 25570, exit code -6]. log files: /home/patrick/.ros/log/63dc7caa-e95e-11e0-a56b-002163a7d4bb/move_base-9*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11338/turtlebot-gmapping-and-amcl-demos-fatal-footprint-error-for-move_base/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-09-28**:
Cool--at least it's not just me. :-)

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-09-28**:
Actually, I take that back... I failed to get the path right on my user account -- I'm now seeing this error.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-09-28**:
Thanks Eitan and Fergs.  rosversion shows I have 1.6.3 of the navigation stack.  I just tried the gmapping_demo again and got the same error.  I did a fresh install of Electric yesterday before getting this error but I'll try it again just to be sure.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2011-09-28**:
Patrick, I can't reproduce this with a fresh install of ros-electric-turtlebot-robot.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-09-28**:
Can you please post the version of navigation that you're running? This sounds like a bug that was fixed awhile ago so I'm wondering if you're up to date or if the debians didn't roll out properly somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, so this is a bug in the navigation stack. You probably notice that you only get this when you *restart* the launch file (it will work the first time). You can make it work again by doing:

```
rosparam delete move_base/local_costmap/footprint
rosparam delete move_base/global_costmap/footprint
```

Basically, the nav stack is storing the footprint calculations back onto the param server after parsing them, but because we don't specify a footprint (as we have a circular robot), we get an error. I'm working on a patch now.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-09-29**:
Works like a charm now.  Thanks!

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-09-28**:
Many thanks Eitan.  I was just in the process of testing it but have to head out the door--good to see that Fergs is still 10x faster than I am at this stuff. :-)

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-09-28**:
Navigation 1.6.4 has the fix, just a matter of time until the debs come out.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-09-28**:
So, things should be fixed in trunk now, I'll also push out a release once things get tested. Sorry for the trouble.

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-09-28**:
OK, this is good to know. There was some code introduced to support dynamic reconfigure that is likely the culprit, I'll have a fix in a second.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-09-28**:
Yeah, I was probably always re-launching because I would mess up some other way, Ctrl-C out of the launch and try again.